# While loop does not end when condition is met

Tags: bash, scripts

I am trying to make a horse betting game that runs in bash
I copied the gpio library to ubuntu from raspbian 
The while loop Does not end when $BET is not 0

```
BET=0
while [ $BET=0 ]
do
    if [ $(gpio read 21) -eq 1 ]
        then
            BET=1
    elif [ $(gpio read 22) -eq 1 ]
        then
            BET=2
    elif [ $(gpio read 23) -eq 1 ]
        then
            BET=3
    elif [ $(gpio read 24) -eq 1 ]
        then
            BET=4 
    elif [ $(gpio read 25) -eq 1 ]
        then
            BET=5
    else
        echo "" > /dev/null 
    fi
    echo $BET
done
```

Why does this not work? Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the point of `echo "" > /dev/null`? That seems completely superfluous. Also, the if-elif sequence could be expressed much more tersely with a for-loop over a range and some arithmetic: `for i in {1..5}; do if [ "$(gpio read $(($i+20)))" -eq 1 ]; then BET=$i; break; fi; done`

Comment: @David I guess the OP simply wanted to insert a _nop_ (no operation) to keep a final `else` block to indicate that the `else` block is intentionally left empty. I sometimes do that in Python (the _nop_ there would be the `pass` keyword). In`bash` the _nop_ is a simple colon `:`. But's that just a guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing some white-space: `[ $BET=0 ]` should be `[ $BET = 0 ]` instead. Better yet, perform a numerical comparison with `[ $BET -eq 0 ]`.

See `man test` for the difference between the three.

P.S.: Run `shellcheck` (from the eponymous package) to help you spot potential flaws and issues in shell scripts. For your script it prints:

```
In - line 2:
while [ $BET=0 ]
        ^-- SC2077: You need spaces around the comparison operator.


In - line 4:
    if [ $(gpio read 21) -eq 1 ]
         ^-- SC2046: Quote this to prevent word splitting.


In - line 7:
    elif [ $(gpio read 22) -eq 1 ]
           ^-- SC2046: Quote this to prevent word splitting.


In - line 10:
    elif [ $(gpio read 23) -eq 1 ]
           ^-- SC2046: Quote this to prevent word splitting.


In - line 13:
    elif [ $(gpio read 24) -eq 1 ]
           ^-- SC2046: Quote this to prevent word splitting.


In - line 16:
    elif [ $(gpio read 25) -eq 1 ]
           ^-- SC2046: Quote this to prevent word splitting.
```

Comment: Thank you So much I have trown about 3 hours into this problem and it was such a simple fix